# <xsl:when test="string-length( xpath value) is not working after xslt version upgrade to xslt 3.0 version

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, string-length, xslt-3.0

<xsl:when test="string-length( xpath value) is not working after xslt version upgrade to xslt 3.0 version>

it is giving error

XPTY0004  A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the first argument of
fn:string-length() ("", "                         ")

but it was working correctly with 1.1 version

Comment: Please provide a **reproducible** example - see: [mcve]. --- I am guessing it worked in XSLT 1.0 because it was actually doing `string-length(some-node[1])` - see: https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-3/#id-incompat-in-false-mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XSLT 1.0, if you called a function such as `string-length()` supplying a set of multiple nodes in the argument, it ignored all nodes except the first.

This led to so many bugs that the rule was changed in 2.0, so supplying more than one node is an error. If you want the first node rule, change `string-length(PATH)` to `string-length((PATH)[1])`. (You can also leave the stylesheet version set to 1.0 to get backwards compatibility mode.)

Answer (score 1):

If you run XSLT `version="1.0"` code (and probably `version="1.1"` code as well) through an XSLT 2 or 3 processor that supports backwards compatible XPath 1.0 mode then some XPath 1.0 specific rules are applied, mainly that functions receiving sequences/node-sets but expecting a single item use the first item in the node-set/sequence.

In standards mode (XSLT version="2.0" or version="3.0") this is not the case, so you need to make sure that your argument to `string-length` is a single string and not a sequence of strings.

Comment: Thanks, it was really helpful to get the proper direction towards the solution.